# Setting readonly property from another class

Tags: c++, readonly

Suppose I have my classes as:

```
namespace scope
{

class A
{
private:
    int a;
public:
    ...
};

class B
{
public:
    ...
    A method();
    ...
};

};
```

The method definition:

```
A B::method()
{
    A object;
    object.a = 3;    // private member access error
                     // access via object (pointer) error if inheritance is used
    return object;
}
```

The most common way to solve the access error is to use setters+getters.

However I don't want any other scope (or someone using the API) to set `A.a`, so a **public setter method is forbidden** for this case.

`a` **may be public** but it should be read-only on API side. It should be **read+write** on the source side, because, for instance, I want to set it with `B::method`. **How can I achieve this behaviour?**

I tried inheritance, also friend relation. I also played with `immutable` and `const` property declarations. The problem with these is, when I declare A object with the default constructor, property is set to some value like -918316838410 (which might arise from the fact that I'm not using `extern`, I'm not sure) and cannot be set by `method` later on.

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Idea 1, define `A` with a public `explicit` constructor that takes an `int`. Idea 2, make `B` a friend of `A`. You say that you tried `friend`, but I suspect you didn't try hard enough.

Comment: default construction for int is an undefined value.
If you want something else, add appropriate constructors.
(eg a no-arg constructor that sets a good value, or a int constructor that takes an argument and uses it).
As for explicit, its unneeded, but often a good idea for one-arg constructor to avoid unintentional automated conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want B to have access to A that you don't want other people to have?

That is friendship.

Add `friend class B`, into the class A definition, and all will be happiness.

btw the common examples for this are when I am using multiple classes to generate a single interface. Eg: things like list<> and map<> usually need node classes, and those classes often want friend access on each other. This breach of encapsulation is fine,  since they are really one big class from a logical perspective.

Be warned, most people should use friends rarely or never, its mostly for library writers, not for general programming.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Richard said, you can use friendship. But keep in mind that when you need friendship, you should probably think again about your design. As Richard saids too, maybe putting a as a parameter of A constructor should do exactly what you want.

Here is a working example with friendship :

```
#include <iostream>
namespace scope
{
class A{
friend class B;
private:
    int a;
public:
    void print(){ 
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
};

class B{
public:
    A method(){
        A a;
        a.a=3;
        return a;
    }
};

int main(){
    scope::B b;
    scope::A a = b.method();
    a.print(); //just to see it works...
}
```

Here is a way to do the same without friendship and keeping a private (Ok its ugly :-)

```
#include <iostream>
namespace scope
{
class B;
class A
{
private:
    int a;
public:
    void print(){
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
    // A way to only allow B instances to give a correct value 
    // of "a" member
    void pleaseClassBSetMyPrivateMember(B& b);
};

class B
{
public:
    A method(){
        A a;
        a.pleaseClassBSetMyPrivateMember(*this);
        return a;
    }

    int computeValueForMemberOfClassA(A& a){
        // you can access public members of a to 
        // calculate the proper value of a.a member
        return 3;
    }

};

void A::pleaseClassBSetMyPrivateMember(B& b)
{
   // ask for class B object the correct value for member a
   a = b.computeValueForMemberOfClassA(*this);
}

};
```